# How to prevent null value from json?

Tags: php, json

Am stored dynamic value in array, and convert json using json_encode, After converting am print json value, But some value return null value, but am printing array value, it display correctly, what can i do, pls help me.

My coding as follows,

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$return=array();
$level=$_REQUEST['level'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM guess WHERE level=$level";
$res = $st->query($sql);
if($res->num_rows>=1){
    $images=array();
    while($row= $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $images[]=$row;
    }
    $return['list']=$images;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

My output in json,

```
{"list":[{"id":"1","type":"text","question":null,"answer":"feed"}]
```

in array,

```
[list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [type] => text
                [question] => WHAT CHARITY Christian organization committed to feeding God’s children hungry in body and spirit?
                [answer] => feed
            )


    )
```

Answer (score 0):

json_encode expects strings in the data to be encoded as UTF-8.

```
   header('Content-type: application/json');
    $return=array();
    $level=$_REQUEST['level'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM guess WHERE level=$level";
    $res = $st->query($sql);
    if($res->num_rows>=1){
        $images=array();
        while($row= $res->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $images[]['id']= ($row['id']);
            $images[]['type']= ($row['type']);
            $images[]['question']= utf8_encode($row['question']);//Convert this to UTF-8 
            $images[]['answer']= ($row['answer']);
        }
        $return['list']= $images;
    }
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But i want value instead of null value in json.

Comment: i have edited my answer with code,Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @  Silambarasan what value u want in place of null

Comment: instead of null i want "WHAT CHARITY Christian organization committed to feeding God’s children hungry in body and spirit?". This value is displayed correctly in array.

Comment: The output of array value are already given in above question.

Comment: i have make some changes in my answer hopefully this time it work

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `IFNULL` function and modify your sql query - so you don't have to write additional php code, since the ifnull function returns 2nd param (your desired string) value if the first param (question column) value is null

```
SELECT col1, col2, IFNULL(question, 'WHAT CHARITY Christian organization committed to feeding God\’s children hungry in body and spirit?') as question  FROM guess WHERE level=$level
```

[for more about ifnull function - click to read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)